# Последовательный вывод товара. Как сделать вывод товара?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

вот есть [скрипт](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1321) выбора элементов последовательно. 
[демо](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1321/demo/index.html)

```
$(function(){

var questions = $('#questions');

function refreshSelects(){
    var selects = questions.find('select');

    // Улучшаем элемент selects с помощью плагина Chose
    selects.chosen();

    // Ждем изменений
    selects.unbind('change').bind('change',function(){

        // Выбранная опция
        var selected = $(this).find('option').eq(this.selectedIndex);
        // Ищем атрибут data-connection
        var connection = selected.data('connection');

        // Удаляем следующий контейнер li (к=если есть)
        selected.closest('#questions li').nextAll().remove();

        if(connection){
            fetchSelect(connection);
        }

    });
}

var working = false;

function fetchSelect(val){

    if(working){
      alert('предлагаем Вам следующие товары: ')
        return false;
    }
    working = true;

    $.getJSON('ajax.php',{key:val},function(r){

        var connection, options = '';

        $.each(r.items,function(k,v){
            connection = '';
            if(v){
                connection = 'data-connection="'+v+'"';
            }

            options+= '<option value="'+k+'" '+connection+'>'+k+'</option>';
        });

        if(r.defaultText){

            // Плагин Chose требует, чтобы был добавлен пустой элемент опции
            // если нужно выводить текст "Пожалуйста, выберите"

            options = '<option></option>'+options;
        }

        // Строим разметку для раздела select

        $('<li>\
            <p>'+r.title+'</p>\
            <select data-placeholder="'+r.defaultText+'">\
                '+ options +'\
            </select>\
            <span class="divider"></span>\
        </li>').appendTo(questions);

        refreshSelects();

        working = false;
    });

}

$('#preloader').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});

// В начале загружаем выбор продукта
fetchSelect('productSelect');
});
```

Подскажите, как вместо последнего селекта выдать результаты в виде активных ссылок? 
Поднимаю вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно, чтобы на основе произведенного выбора обрабатывались полученные данные, и на их основе выводился список, соответствующий условию. Для этого в js-скрипте нужно дописать обработку данных:

```
if(working){
      // вот здесь
      return false;
}
```

Comment: В этом коде working же никогда не будет true?

Comment: Как написать обработку данных?